# How can I access the dictionary returned from my results?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I created a function using beutifulsoup that returns what looks like a dictionary of reults. but if I try

```
results['file']
```

or

```
results[0]
```

it doesn't return the results I want. I want the file and image. heres my code

```
    def panties():
        pan_url = 'http://www.panvideos.com'
        html = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})

        def youtube_link(url):
            youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
            video_row = soupdata.find('div', {'class': 'video-player'})
            entries = [{'text': str(div),
                        } for div in video_row][3]['text']

            oldstring = str(entries)
            removed = '<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer("video-setup").setup('
            newstring = oldstring.replace(removed, "")
            removed_two = ');</script>'
            newstring_two = newstring.replace(removed_two, "")

            return newstring_two

        entries = [{'text': div.h4.text,
                    'href': div.a.get('href'),
                    'tube': youtube_link(div.a.get('href')),
                    } for div in video_row][:1]

        return entries
```

and heres what it returns

```
{file:"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jucBuAzuZ0E",image:"http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/jucBuAzuZ0E/maxresdefault.jpg",primary:"html5",stretching:"fill","controlbar":"bottom",width:"100%",aspectratio:"16:9",autostart:"true",logo:{file:"http://www.panvideos.com/uploads/bien-png578aab16676e1.png",position:"bottom-right",link:"http://www.panvideos.com/"},sharing:{link:"http://www.panvideos.com/video/3020/alejandro-sanz-deja-que-te-bese-ft-marc-anthony-official-video-/","sites":["facebook","twitter","linkedin","pinterest","tumblr","googleplus","reddit"]}}
```

all I really want is

```
file:"http://www.youtube.com/watchv=jucBuAzuZ0E"
image:"http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/jucBuAzuZ0E/maxresdefault.jpg"
```

how do I grab this? I'm using django and i tried doing this

```
{% for p in pan %}
   Title: {{p.text}}<br>
   Href: {{p.href}}<br>
   Tube: {{p.tube['file']}}<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

but I got a parsing error. How can I access file and image?

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {file:"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jucBuAzuZ0E",image:"http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/jucBuAzuZ0E/maxresdefault.jpg",primary:"html5",stretching:"fill","controlbar":"bottom",width:"100%",aspectratio:"16:9",autostart:"true",logo:{file:"http://www.panvideos.com/uploads/bien-png578aab16676e1.png",position:"bottom-right",link:"http://www.panvideos.com/"},sharing:{link:"http://www.panvideos.com/video/3020/alejandro-sanz-deja-que-te-bese-ft-marc-anthony-official-video-/","sites":["facebook","twitter","linkedin","pinterest","tumblr","googleplus","reddit"]}}
```

you have to edit your view file where you are returning just entities (I have used dict variable instead of entities) as

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {'dict': dict})
```

To render the value in html template:

```
 <p>{{ dict.file }}</p>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response @aroy but where would this go in my code. and the dictionary must be unique to each video im pulling. It seems like you want me to put that in my views

Comment: if you are specifying pan as dictionary what you need to do is {% for key,value in pan.items %} where you are extracting file just use {{ pan.items.key }}

Comment: got this idea from https://gun.io/blog/how-to-list-items-in-a-dictionary-in-a-django-template/  Hope it resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting back a dictionary, and in order to parse through a dictionary just use the names assigned to the values.

Example:
if you only want the file and image use:

```
results["file"]
results["image"]
```

or you may need to use:

```
entries["file"]
entries["image"]
```

hope that solves your problem :)

Comment: tried that already and get the following message "string indices must be integers"

Answer (score -1):

dict.iteritems() method returns an iterator over the dictionary’s (key, value) pairs.

```
for k, v in yourdict.iteritems():
    print(k ,v)
```